# ordered terms + selecting terms in tab_model

Tags: r

I have a MLM to report which i saved as .rds file and load. But i need to report only several coefficients and in a particular order.

I set my labels for coefficients:

```
coefs =c(
"mother_l1_recode1"=  "Northern European",
"mother_l1_recode2"=  "Southern European",
"mother_l1_recode3"=  "Eastern European",
"mother_l1_recode4"=  "Southwest and Central Asian",
"mother_l1_recode5"=  "Southern Asian",
"mother_l1_recode6"=  "Southeast Asian",
"mother_l1_recode7"=  "Eastern Asian",
"mother_l1_recode9"=  "Other",
"mother_l1_recodenot_provided"=  "Not provided",
"mother_dummy_12011"=  "Non English"
)
```

And included the list of terms as `terms` in the order I need them, but eventually, the print does not come in this order. How can I fix this?

```
tab_model(mlm1, mlm1_non1201,
          title=" ",
          pred.labels=coefs,

        terms = c(
          "mother_l1_recode1", 
          "mother_l1_recode2",
          "mother_l1_recode3", 
          "mother_l1_recode4",
          "mother_l1_recode5", 
          "mother_l1_recode6",
          "mother_l1_recode7", 
          "mother_l1_recode9",
          "mother_l1_recodenot_provided"
        ),
          show.intercept = FALSE,
          show.ci=FALSE,
          show.se = TRUE,
          string.se = "S.E.",
          dv.labels = c(
            paste("Year", parse_number(Year_Level_2_use), sep=" "),
            paste("Year", parse_number(Year_Level_2_use)+4, sep=" ")
          ),
          string.pred = as.character(year),
          string.est = "Coefficient",
          p.style="stars", 
        show.icc = FALSE,
      show.re.var = FALSE,
      show.obs = FALSE,
      show.r2 =FALSE,
      show.ngroups = FALSE,
          auto.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: in `sjPlot` package there is a `order.terms` argument for at least `plot_model()` function. Maybe it works also for tables in `tab_model()` function. [see here](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/plot_model_estimates.html)

Comment: I tried `order.terms` but it pulls up all coefficients and ignores `terms` option altogether